# object orientation, inheritance, and composition in c++

Tags: c++, oop

There are 4 classes: A, B, C, and D.  Class A "HAS A" B, and class C "HAS A" D.  As it happens, C "IS A" A, and D "IS A" B.  What's the best way to model these relationships in C++?

The B that A has is the same D that C has.

Example: A building has an entrance, and a house has a door. A house is a building, and a door is an entrance.

Comment: Is this a homework exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a flaw in your design. If I understand correctly, you want to restrict the type of a base class member variable:

```
struct Entrance {};
struct Door : public Entrance {};

struct Building
{
    Entrance * entrance; // raw pointer just for the sake of clarity
};

struct House : public Building
{
    // Building::entrance must always be a door
};
```

You could achieve that using accessors (getter/setter) to `entrance` and checking the type, throwing an exception if the entrance is not a door, but that would break the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): you would not be able to manipulate `House`s as if they were `Building`s:

```
struct Drawbridge : public Entrance {};

House house;
Drawbridge bridge;

Building & building = house;
building.setEntrance(bridge); 
// Oups, I'm trying to install a drawbridge on my house!
```

Some libraries perform this kind of restrictions (for example, [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) throws an exception when one try to modify its content), but in my opinion, this is not a clean design. If collection's interface states that I can [add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc672239.aspx) elements to the collection, then a read only collection is **not** a collection (since it does not support adding elements).

The same reasoning can be applied here: a `House` is **not** a `Building` since it cannot contain all kind of `Entrance`s.

Comment: Whilst correct, I think it stands to reason that this is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Tomalak: Well, the first part of the answer gives some hints to answer the actual question (without going into too much details since I suspect a homework question). And the second part is clearly a bit off-topic, but I don't like to miss opportunities to give some OO design advices to beginners.

Comment: Oh, I agree. I think that it should stay up for sure. (And I _had_ missed that the first part of the answer _is_ essentially what the OP is asking for, or one approach at it at least)

Answer (score 3):

```
class B {
};
class A {
  B b;  // A "has a" B
};
class C : public A  { // C "is a" A
  D d;  // C "has a" D
};
class D : public B { // D "is a" B
};
```

Comment: I edited my post.  The D in class C is the same as the B in class A, so I don't want both a D and B in class C.

Comment: @Robert, your question still not clear. Do you want `C "has a" D` relationship or not ?

Comment: Yes. Example: A building has an entrance, and a house has a door.  A house is a building, and a door is an entrance.

Comment: If you don't want `C "has a" D` relationship then you can remove that part from your question. And to incorporate that we have to remove `D d;` from the answer I gave.

Comment: If you remove `D d;` then C "has a" B, not a D.

Comment: -1: This answer has now been incorrect for a lot longer than it was correct.

Comment: @Tomalak, please read the words carefully; I said the "original question" (which are the 1st two lines of the question). My answer satisfies the same. I still don't see any edit there. What you are talking is about "EDIT1" and "EDIT2", which are unclear and not matching with the original question. Request you to take back your unreasonable downvote.

Comment: @iammilind: What nonsense are you spewing now? The two edits update the original question. If it makes you feel better, you can ignore the words "edit" as you read it, and then it will all be one big question again. This answer does _not_ answer the stated question, and hasn't done since very soon after it was posted. And that's it.

Comment: @Tomalak, doesn't matter if I am happy or not. I still don't see how the 1st two lines (original question) and the new edits relate to each other. Do whatever you want. At least you are happy justifying your downvote. <Discussion closed>.

Comment: What is confusing about it? The first two lines state facts about the required class heirarchy. The third line states another fact. The fourth line is an analogy for internal visualisation.

Answer (score 1):

> A building has an entrance, and a house has a door. A house is a building, and a door is an entrance.

```
struct Entrance        {};
struct Door : Entrance {};

struct Building {
   virtual Entrance& getEntrance() = 0;
};

struct House : Building {
   virtual Entrance& getEntrance() {
      return entrance;
   }

   private:
   Door entrance;
};

typedef Building A;
typedef Entrance B;
typedef House    C;
typedef Door     D;
```

This is the nearest approximation, using polymorphism. Note in particular that `Building` cannot be instantiated because it is "abstract".

Otherwise, you cannot have `A` has-a `B` *and* `C` has-a `D`, *and* have both the `B` and the `D` be the same object.

---

If you get tempted to attempt to have the base hold a *reference*, avoid it:

```
struct Entrance        {};
struct Door : Entrance {};

struct Building {
   Building(Entrance& e) : e(e) {}
   Entrance& e;
};

struct House : Building {
   House() : Building(e) {}
   Door e;
};

typedef Building A;
typedef Entrance B;
typedef House    C;
typedef Door     D;
```

Since `House`'s `Building` constructor is invoked before its `Door` is created, **this is questionable at best** (and undefined at worst.. I'd have to look it up).

---

Luc is right, though, that this modelling is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

C extends A and D extends B. A holds a B object in its definition and C holds a D object. 
[[Has-a]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a)
[[Is-a]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a)

Comment: IMO, ["has a" relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) is related to composite type; it deals with objects and not with references.

Comment: ah i see this is a c++ question. i was referring to the case in java where d in D d = new D() is a reference to a D object. however, i do agree that composite relations refer to objects so perhaps my answer was clear enough.